# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly xampp .This may be due to a blocked port Can someone help out so that i can start using the xampp server?

Tags: mysql, xampp

Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums

Comment: Did you check MySQL error log? Can you share error logs here ?

Comment: How to check the error log ? can you tell me the steps ?

Comment: Did you check your MySQL data directory.. It might look like "C:/xampp/mysql/data/" or you better find your MySQL configuration file and look for "error" variable.

Comment: The data directory consists of many files which file should i check ?

Comment: look for error named file.

Comment: Hey I changed the port number and sql is starting now . But still facing some errors in the Connectivity  part though